# Maven build error - Unauthorized

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, azure-pipelines

I am new to maven. Any suggestion on below maven build error will be helpful for me. I am using command **"mvn clean install"** to build the application

```
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata mycompany-myvault:mycompany-myvault-models-common:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\build_account\.m2\repository)
[DEBUG] Using transporter WagonTransporter with priority -1.0 for https://mycompany-marketing.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/mycompany.myvault.Packages/maven/v1
[DEBUG] Using connector BasicRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for https://mycompany-marketing.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/mycompany.myvault.Packages/maven/v1 via proxy-azsu.azure.uk.mycompanyplc.com:8080
Downloading: https://mycompany-marketing.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/mycompany.myvault.Packages/maven/v1/mycompany-myvault/mycompany-myvault-models-common/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[DEBUG] Writing tracking file C:\Users\build_account\.m2\repository\mycompany-myvault\mycompany-myvault-models-common\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\resolver-status.properties
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata mycompany-myvault:mycompany-myvault-models-common:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to mycompany-marketing-visualstudio.com-mycompany.myvault.packages (https://mycompany-marketing.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/mycompany.myvault.Packages/maven/v1): Not authorized , ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized.
org.eclipse.aether.transfer.MetadataTransferException: Could not transfer metadata mycompany-myvault:mycompany-myvault-models-common:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to mycompany-marketing-visualstudio.com-mycompany.myvault.packages (https://mycompany-marketing.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/mycompany.myvault.Packages/maven/v1): Not authorized , ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized.
```

Comment: Well. Unauthorized means unauthorized.Check your credentials for your artifact repository

Comment: Apart from that are you really like to use a Maven repository with Version 1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding below credential in Settings.xml fixed this issue. In vsts you can generate maven credential via Packages -> Connect to Feed -> Generate maven credentials. It will generate credentials as below and put it under  in settings.xml

```xml
<server>
 <id>mycompany-marketing-visualstudio.com-mycompany.myvault.packages</id>
 <configuration>
  <httpHeaders>
   <property>
    <name>Authorization</name>   
    <value>Basic 5asdfasdfasdfaTASDFasdfadfasdfasddfadsasdfasdf as34asfase4asdfasfsadfdfgfdgrfgrtetryuikmnbvfft6iuopuytrewwsdfghjj</value>
   </property>
  </httpHeaders>
 </configuration>
</server>
```